# Attempting to connect to mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js

Let me start off by saying that I am a complete beginner with javascript.  I am trying to read up on it and learn it. I have a MySQL database hosted with GoDaddy and am attempting to connect to it with a discord bot. Here is the code below:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'redacted',
    port     : 'redacted'
    user     : 'redacted',
    password : 'redacted',
    database : 'redacted'
});

con.connect(error => {
    if(error) throw error;
    msg.channel.send("Connection to database successful!");
});


client.login('redacted');
```

When I run node index.js, the error is:

```
     user     : 'redacted',
    ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

I don't understand why "user" is an unexpected identifier.  Can anyone steer my in the right direction?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have left off the comma after the redacted port.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the comma `,` in the previous line of code

```
port     : 'redacted',
```